# Double resolution texture makes item too big only when in player's hand

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

In my resource pack, most of the textures are the default resolution (16x16) but two item textures are 32x32 instead. These mostly display correctly, *except* when held in the player's hand. Then, the higher resolution items appear too big. In the inventory/Creative menu, and when dropped on the ground, the items are all the correct size, regardless of texture resolution.

Here is an example of the double resolution item (the squid tentacle) on the ground beside two standard resolution items:
[image: items on ground all have correct sizes]

And here is the player holding a 32x item (the same squid tentacle) and a 16x item (the fish):
[image: too big 32x item in hand]
[image: normal 16x item in hand]

Is there a way to scale down the higher resolution item's size when in the player's hand, so that it matches the other items?

---

This is the image I'm using for the item texture: [image: squid tentacle item texture]

And here is squid.item.json from the behavior pack:

```
{  
  "format_version": "1.20.30",  
  "minecraft:item": {  
        "description": {  
            "identifier": "addtns:squid",  
            "menu_category": {  
                "group": "itemGroup.name.rawFood",
                "category": "nature"
            }  
        },  
        "components": {
            "minecraft:hand_equipped": false,
            "minecraft:max_stack_size": 64,
            "minecraft:icon": {  
                "texture": "squid"  
            },  
            "minecraft:display_name": {  
                "value": "Squid"  
            },
            "minecraft:use_duration": 2,
            "minecraft:use_animation": "eat",
            "minecraft:food": {
                "nutrition": 3,
                "saturation_modifier": 0.4,
                "can_always_eat": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In MCJava, there are item models. Are you using something like that in MCBE, too? If yes, please attach it. Do other 32×32 packs work as expected?

Comment: @FabianRöling I'm not using a custom model for the item, just a .png texture and the JSON files. (I will update the question to include all relevant files and the image.) The squid is a custom item, not a retextured vanilla item. I haven't tried other 32x32 packs - the pack I'm working on is meant to be 16x16, except for the squid tentacle because the suction cups weren't distinct at that resolution.

Comment: In MCJava, models are JSON.